# Should I define computed property of inside of protocol if the extension with implementation follows?

Tags: ios, swift, coding-style

What's the difference between:

```
protocol DashboardTargetInfo: TargetInfo {
    var apiVersion: Int { get }
}

extension DashboardTargetInfo {
    var apiVersion: Int {
        5
    }
}
```

And the one without computed property included in protocol definition

```
protocol DashboardTargetInfo: TargetInfo {}

extension DashboardTargetInfo {
    
    var apiVersion: Int {
        5
    }
}
```

Should I include the definition of the computed "apiVersion" property if the extension definition is following? Is there any difference between those two snippets of code?

Answer (score 3):

In the first version apiVersion is part of the protocol and any conforming types must implement the property or use the default one. In the second one this is just a computed property that is available for types conforming to it and not part of the protocol.

An example:

```
struct Test1: DashboardTargetInfo { var apiVersion: Int }
struct Test2: DashboardTargetInfo { var apiVersion: Int { 10 } }

let values: [DashboardTargetInfo] = [Test1(apiVersion: 42), Test2()]
print(values.map(\.apiVersion))
```

With the first version of the protocol we get the values of the conforming types

> [42, 10]

But if our types conforms to the second example then `apiVersion` is not part of the protocol so only the default computed value is used

> [5, 5]

Comment: The second [5,5] output is surprising. Why the computed property of protocol is used and not the apiVersion computed property defined in the struct?
(And why have you used ***any DashboardTargetInfo*** as a type for things in an array and not just ***DashboardTargetInfo***?)

Comment: Because the array is declared to contain objects that conform to the protocol so what the compiler sees is the computed property in the extension of the protocol. It knows nothing about the underlying types other than that they conform to the protocol DashboardTargetInfo. `any` isn't needed here, that was a typo